# unable to create table using dbDelta in my wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

i am unable to create a custom table using dbDelta in my plugin.

[image]

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to Stackoverflow.  This question needs more details so that someone can actually help you.  Specifically, what are the hooks you're using to fire this function?  This would be equally as relevant to your issue.  You should consider reading [ask] and [mre] and [Why not post pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for ; at the end of Primary Key ('id'). You can use this code instead :

```
add_action('admin_init', 'prefix_create_db_table', 15);
function prefix_create_db_table() {
  global $wpdb;
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
  $DBP_tb_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'DBP_db_login';
  $sql = "
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$DBP_tb_name}` 
    ( 
      `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
      `name` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT '' , 
      `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL , 
      `expires_at` DATETIME NOT NULL , 
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) {$wpdb->get_charset_collate()}
   ";
   dbDelta( $sql );
 }
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a good answer? Do you know the way the user is hooking in their function?  Maybe that is the problem?  The question is a poor quality question.

Comment: @HowardE You're right, I added some more details dude ( although the question is a poor question)

Comment: Answering poor questions isn't the way to earn quick reputation points.  Additionally, you don't want to call dbdelta on every admin init.  This is something that should be used on plugin activation script.  Also, by adding arbitrary `add_action` to make your answer better, you really don't know if you're answering the question, since the question isn't specific enough for a reasonable answer.